# CiviCRM Architecture - CiviCRM directory structure

Tags: api, architecture

Can anybody help me understand the architecture and directory structure of the civicrm. I found [this post](https://civicrm.org/blogs/civicrm-team/civicrm-architecture-civicrm-directory-structure) written in 2006 which doesn't seems to be valid for newer version.

Answer (score 1):

this is still mostly valid, with the addition of the api folder that contains, you guessed it, the api goodness.

You might have several folders missing depending on how you install it. eg all the test and xml folders are only there if you install a full/development environment, not if you download the pre-packaged production version

What is missing or unclear?